# How to get file name from asset uri in React Native

Tags: react-native, filesystems, assets, camera-roll

I want to be able to get the file name and type from an image from my camera roll. Here is the link to the file:

`"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=ED7AC36B-A150-4C38-BB8C-B6D696F4F2ED&ext=JPG"`

How do I extract the file name and `mime type` from here. I'm particularly interested in the `mime type` because I can generate random names but I need to be correct on the type when uploading the file.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, there is a really good package to handle this called [expo-asset-utils](https://github.com/expo/expo-asset-utils).

```
import AssetUtils from 'expo-asset-utils';    
const { localUri, width, height } = await AssetUtils.resolveAsync(uri);
// localUri now contains the converted URI to a 'file://' URI
```

Answer (score 0):

try out npm i expo_file_name

import {**getFileName**} from '**expo_file_name**'

const uri = //the value for the uri goes here

const **fileName** = getFileName(uri);

//the name of the file is then stored in the **fileName** variable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).